# Django-ORM - passing annotated column names into a Subquery?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-2.2

I have constructed the following query "chain":

```
survey_results = OrganisationSurveyResult.objects.filter(user=user)

survey_results = survey_results.filter(
    created_date__in=survey_results.values(
        'user', 'organisation_survey'
    ).annotate(
        latest_created_date=Max('created_date')
    ).values(
        'latest_created_date'
    )
).annotate(
    module=F('organisation_survey__survey__module'),
    score=F('survey_result__normalized_score'),
    rank=F('survey_result__rank_class'),
).values(
    'module', 'score', 'rank', 'created_date'
)
```

Which returns the following entries when iterated:

```
{'created_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 15, 10, 54, 214754, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'module': UUID('151cb049-65c5-4278-8133-610859be6f34'), 'score': 95, 'rank': 'Low'}
{'created_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 15, 10, 54, 220694, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'module': UUID('7c5848eb-3090-4819-8eac-166367ab0e65'), 'score': 91, 'rank': 'Low'}
{'created_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 15, 10, 54, 226334, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'module': UUID('b894c988-af3d-4ecb-a2a1-c42225b64b71'), 'score': 100, 'rank': 'Low'}
{'created_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 15, 10, 54, 232898, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'module': UUID('22edce11-f78e-4b2e-a1de-1ecc7f0518c9'), 'score': 59, 'rank': 'Medium'}
```

The request-response cycle for this API endpoint is 51-89ms. The DB query time is 24-38ms. It was originally 1280ms as I was using a `prefetch_related` method and looping.

It's also passed all tests. It has four record entries for a single user (there are only four modules). Each date in the list of entries is also the last `SurveyResult` for that module and user. Happy so far.

However, my next step is for each of the above entries in the list, I need to obtain the following:

```
for survey_result in survey_results.iterator():
    resource = Resource.objects.filter(module=survey_result['module'], rank_class=survey_result['rank'])
```

So, I am adding an extra 4 queries to this endpoint. Could be more in time as more modules are added.

The total bathing time for adding this pushes the query time to 44-111ms from 24-38ms.

Would anyone know a nifty way of cutting the 4 queries into one? Perhaps extending the original query somehow with some clever annotations?

I was maybe thinking maybe utilising some sort of `Subquery`? But how could I pass in the annotated fields from above into the `Subquery`?

```
survey_results = OrganisationSurveyResult.objects.filter(user=user)

survey_results = survey_results.filter(
    created_date__in=survey_results.values(
        'user', 'organisation_survey'
    ).annotate(
        latest_created_date=Max('created_date')
    ).values(
        'latest_created_date'
    )
).annotate(
    module=F('organisation_survey__survey__module'),
    rank_class=F('survey_result__rank_class'),
).annotate(
    resource=Subquery(
        Resource.objects.filter(
            module=module,
            rank_class=rank_class,
        ).order_by('?')[0]
    )
).values(
    'resource'
)
```

**Django version**: 2.2.2

Comment: Use `OuterRef` (`OuterRef('module')`)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for this. However, I am getting the following validation error: `["'OuterRef(module)' is not a valid UUID."]`. It looks like this could be a bug with using UUID fields as primary keys?

Comment: It should be `OuterRef("module")` not `OuterRef(module)`

Comment: @dirkgroten Just to confirm, the above error is being thrown when using `Resource.objects.filter(module=OuterRef(OuterRef('module')), rank_class=OuterRef(OuterRef('rank_class')))` inside the `Subquery`.

Comment: why the double wrap? `module=OuterRef('module')` should do the trick. Sorry, my first comment might have been a bit misleading: the parenthesis was an example for how to use it (it's not inside the code)...

Comment: @dirkgroten I think I'm using it because you said to...?

Comment: @dirkgroten Also, the single wrap gives a new error: `This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

Comment: my comments was supposed to be read: use `OuterRef` (e.g. `OuterRef('module')`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198192/discussion-between-wind-up-lord-vexxos-and-dirkgroten).

Comment: @dirkgroten Please see above comment - both the single and double `OuterRef()` methods do not work. See error above.